# Set default value of a richeditor field in fields.yaml (context: create)

Tags: yaml, octobercms

What I need is a possibility to edit the email message before sending it upon creation of a model. The email message is already created under /system/mailtemplates I just need to place it in richeditor.

My fields.yaml file looks like this:

```
    [...]
    _email_contents:
        type: richeditor
        size: huge
        tab: 'Add licenses'
        default: acme.license::mail.license_granted
        context:
            - create
        trigger:
            action: show
            field: _send_email_to_admin
            condition: checked
```

So how can I place the email template **acme.license::mail.license_granted** into **default** value?

this: **default: acme.license::mail.license_granted** just echoes 'acme.license::mail.license_granted' in richeditor instead of the content of email template.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using yaml file, I have extended the controller like this:

```
    public function formExtendFields($form)
{

    $email_template = \System\Models\MailTemplate::findOrMakeTemplate('acme.plugin::mail.license_granted');


    $form->addFields([
        '_email_contents' => [
                'type' => 'richeditor',
                'size' => 'huge',
                'tab' => 'Add licenses',
                'default' => $email_template->content_html,
                'context' => 'create',
                'trigger' => [
                    'action' => 'show',
                    'field' => '_send_email_to_admin',
                    'condition' => 'checked'
                ]
            ]
    ]);
}
```

This way I can send the email template as default value. That almost solves my problem - almost because the email template is stripped from html tags ... But that is an issue for another question.